# groovy create file and put image in it

Tags: java, groovy

Hi I'm getting an image request, and i'm saving it this way

```
def th = Thread.start {
   def file = new File(destinationFileName)
   file.mkdirs()
   f.transferTo(file)
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /..../5.jpg (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo(CommonsMultipartFile.java:133)
```

Is there any reason for the directories and files not to be created? (I tried creating them from the shell, and it works fine)

Answer (score 0):

I'd call `file.createNewFile()` after `mkdirs()`